# Get all previous items from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array filled with these strings for example:

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5";
```

I have an `foreach()` loop, that loops through these items. It outputs all the items. Now, it outputs this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

But I want to output this:

```
1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345
```

How do I do this? Because the `prev()` function only applies to the one before the current item.

My code:

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
foreach ($array as $item){
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: Concat them as a string for each iteration?

Comment: for loop + `array_slice()`

Comment: `foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo implode(array_slice($data, 0, $key+1)), PHP_EOL;
}` or `foreach(array_keys($data) as $key) {
    echo implode(array_slice($data, 0, $key+1)), PHP_EOL;
}`

Comment: Don't you have any idea? It's an easy task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$include = "";
foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $include . $item;
    $include .= $item;
}
```

Separators version:

```
$string = "";
$include = "";
foreach($array as $item) {
    $string .= $include . $item . ", ";
    $include .= $item;
}
echo rtrim($string, ', \t\n');
```

Comment: Really want to mark it accepted, but I have to wait five more minutes haha. And I have been busy with PHP for some time now, that's why I got very frustrated for not knowing this :p

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions just don't come to mind, I almost over complicated this myself.

Comment: What about separators ?

Comment: I'm sure he's smart enough to figure out separators :) - but, just for you ;)

Comment: Also for reference, the code he provided didn't have separators ;)

Comment: @JamesLalor he saidthe expected output:  "1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345", and if he's not able to do a simple concat, I wouldn't bet on his capability to add separators... :p

Comment: Aye, but his output code from his code said 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - So I assumed he was adding commas himself to help us understand ;)

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the current item each time through:

```
$output = '';
foreach ($array as $item){
    $output .= $item;
    echo $output;
}
```

For a comma separated list you can create an array and implode:

```
$items = '';
foreach ($array as $item){
    $items .= $item;
    $output[] = $items;
}
echo implode(', ', $output);
```

Comment: What about separators... ?

Comment: Yay ! So much better :)

Answer (score 1):

concatination in php be executed by .(point)

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$temp = '';
$output = '';
foreach ($array as $item){
    $temp .= $item;
    $output .= $temp . ',';
}
echo rtrim($output,',');
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation (and is never just code only) of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$value = '';

foreach ($array as $item){
    $value .= $item;
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation (and is never just code only) of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron If you take note, please add explainations of what you do, not just code. By the way this does not provide the expected output... Missing separators etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$concatItem = "";
foreach ($array as $item){
    $concatItem = $concatItem.$item;
    echo $concatItem;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation (and is never just code only) of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: What about separators ?

Answer (score 0):

use like this way...

```
<?php

$array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$separate = $array;
$series =' ';


foreach ($array as $item){
    $series .=$item;
    echo $series;
    if (next($separate )) {
        echo ','; // Add comma for all elements instead of last
    }
}

?>
```

Output..
[image]